# VBA divide by 1000 for cell that is not highlighted in yellow

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using this basic code to divide the value of a cell by 1000:

```
Sub Divide_by_1000()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        cell = cell / 1000
    Next
 End Sub
```

But I am wondering if I can change the lines to enable the code to only divide the cell by 1000 if the cell is not highlighted in yellow. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thank you very much.

Since the cells that I want to "divide by 1000" spread around quite randomly, I need to manually select those cells that I don't want to divide them by 1000 and highlight them in yellow. But I am wondering if there is a code that can filter out the ones that are not highlighted in yellow and then divide them by 1000. Thank you.

Comment: After the For `Each Cell in Selection` you could test with something like `If Cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then`

Comment: How are the cells highlighted? manually or with conditional formatting?

Comment: The cells are highlighted manually. Also I found this basic code online. But I feel the range isn't correct and can't apply to my case. Could anyone maybe provide a more complete block of code? I only know a little bit of python but I'm not quite familiar with this language :(

Answer (score 1):

### Divide and Highlight

[image]

```vb
Sub DivideAndHighlight()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Divide and Highlight"
    Const DIVISOR As Double = 1000
    Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR As Long = vbYellow
    
    If Selection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub ' not a range
    
    Dim urg As Range, cell As Range, cValue
    
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        If cell.Interior.Color <> HIGHLIGHT_COLOR Then
            cValue = cell.Value
            If VarType(cValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                If urg Is Nothing Then
                    Set urg = cell
                Else
                    Set urg = Union(urg, cell)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    If urg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cells found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim arg As Range, Data, rCount As Long, cCount As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    
    For Each arg In urg.Areas
        
        rCount = arg.Rows.Count
        cCount = arg.Columns.Count
        
        If rCount * cCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = arg.Value
        Else
            Data = arg.Value
        End If
        
        For r = 1 To rCount
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(r, c) = Data(r, c) / DIVISOR
            Next c
        Next r
        
        arg.Value = Data
    
    Next arg
    
    urg.Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR
    
    MsgBox "Cells divided and highlighted.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I create a command button and then input the code there? But after I putting in the code and pressing the button, it returns "no cells found".

Comment: After you have manually selected a range, after running the code, each cell whose value is a number, and that is not highlighted in yellow, will be divided by 1000 and highlighted in yellow (the latter preventing multiple divisions). When you run the code with the same selection again, the mentioned message will appear because all cells have already been divided and highlighted. You don't want to divide the cells multiple times and you don't want to divide the yellow cells, right? Or do you?